# How to use a placeholder with openpyxl conditional formatting?

Tags: python, typeerror, openpyxl

I'm still relatively new to Python, but played around with this for a while and can't wrap my head around it.

I have a query that returns data into a spreadsheet using Openpyxl, and I want to conditional format that spreadsheet. I can do it if I put in the exact number of rows, but the number of rows varies depending on the query, so I am trying to get it to only conditional format the number of rows I have, so I need a placeholder as you can see below. I use a variable `num_of_rows` that returns the number of rows. I want to say:

```
ws.conditional_formatting.add(('H3:H%d', CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['10'],
                               stopIfTrue=True, fill=red_fill)) % (num_of_rows,))
```

But I get this error:

```
ws.conditional_formatting.add(('H3:H%d',
CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['10'], stopIfTrue=True,
fill=red_fill)) % (15,))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

Even if I change the `num_of_rows` variable after the `%` to a number, say `15`, it returns the same error. How do I use a placeholder here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead

`ws.conditional_formatting.add(('H3:H%d' % (num_of_rows,), CellIsRule(operator='lessThan', formula=['10'], stopIfTrue=True, fill=red_fill)))`

The reason is you have to use the `%` operator right after the string but instead you're trying to use it on the `ws.conditional_formatting.add()` function.

Comment: D'oh! Just figured it out right after I posted it, and that's exactly what I did to get it to work. Thanks so much!

Comment: FWIW the use of the string `.format()` method is preferred over `printf` formatting.